# INSERT IGNORE In mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder whether someone can help me please.

I'm trying to put together a PHP script that takes data from an xml file and places the data in a mySQL data. I've been working on this for a few days and I'm still can't seem to get this right.

This is the code that I've managed to put together:

```
    <? 

      $objDOM = new DOMDocument(); 
      $objDOM->load("xmlfile.xml"); 

      $Details = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("Details"); 

      foreach( $Details as $value ) 
      { 

        $listentry = $value->getElementsByTagName("listentry"); 
        $listentrys  = $listentry->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $sitetype = $value->getElementsByTagName("sitetype"); 
        $sitetypes  = $sitetype->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $sitedescription = $value->getElementsByTagName("sitedescription"); 
        $sitedescriptions  = $sitedescription->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $siteosgb36lat = $value->getElementsByTagName("siteosgb36lat"); 
        $siteosgb36lats  = $siteosgb36lat->item(0)->nodeValue;

        $siteosgb36lon = $value->getElementsByTagName("siteosgb36lon"); 
        $siteosgb36lons  = $siteosgb36lon->item(0)->nodeValue;

        //echo "$listentrys :: $sitetypes :: $sitedescriptions :: $siteosgb36lats ::         $siteosgb36lons <br>"; 


      } 

    require("phpfile.php");

    //Opens a connection to a MySQL server
    $connection = mysql_connect ("hostname", $username, $password);
    if (!$connection) {
     die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
    }

    // Set the active MySQL database
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
    if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
    }

   mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO scheduledsites (listentry, sitetype, sitedescription, siteosgb36lat, siteosgb36lon) VALUES('$listentrys','$sitetypes','$sitedescriptions','$siteosgb36lats','$siteosgb36lons') ")  
or die(mysql_error());  


    echo "Data Inserted!"; 


?>
```

I can pull the data from the xml file, but it's the part of the script that sends the data to my database table that I'm having trouble with.

The script runs but only the last record is saved to the database.

I can parse the fields from the xml file without any problems and the check I'm trying to put in place is, if there is a 'listentry' number in the new data that is matched to one already in the table then I don't want that record to be added to the table, i.e. ignore it.

I just wondered whether someone could perhaps take a look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks

Comment: show your db structure with indexes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only calling `mysql_query` once.  So it will only insert one row.

The sql needs to be inside the loop.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for replying to my post. Apologies I'm really quite new to this, could you perhaps elaborate what I need to do a little further please? Kind regards

Comment: Hi, worked it out. Bit of a stupid moment there. Kind regards.